# Prolog-SWI Can't figure out how to recursively multiply Polynomials

Tags: prolog

Here's what I was trying to do

```
%polynomials
eval_term([C|E], X, N) :- N is (X**E)*C.

eval_poly([],[]) :- !.

eval_poly([[H|T]|[]], X, N) :-
    eval_term([H|T], X, N2),
    N is N+N2,
    !.
eval_poly([[H|T]|Rest], X, N) :-
    eval_term([H|T], X, N2),
    N is N+N2,
    eval_poly(Rest, X, N).
```

Here's a sample of what would be inputted

```
?-  eval_poly([[1 | 2], [2 | 1], [3 | 0]], 2, N).
```

which would output 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean code is better, so here is a cleaned up - and corrected - version of what you provided.

```erlang
eval_term([C|E], X, N) :- N is (X**E)*C.

% useless
% eval_poly([],[]) :- !.

eval_poly([Mono], X, N) :-
    eval_term(Mono, X, N).

eval_poly([Mono|Rest], X, N) :-
    eval_term(Mono, X, MV),
    eval_poly(Rest, X, RV),
    N is MV+RV.
```

Your primary mistake was `N is N+N2`, that doesn't make sense in Prolog.
Variables (N in this case) does **not** get assigned, but unified.
Indeed the is/2 operator introduces a sublanguage (arithmetic expressions evaluation) in the right operand, and *unifies* the result with the left operand.
Since `N` is used in the right operand, there is little chance the unification could succeed (you should be able to find out what values the *variables* `N` and `N2` should be *bounded* for this to happen).

Now for a more idiomatic solution:

```erlang
eval_term_(X, [C|E], N) :- N is (X**E)*C.
eval_poly_(Poly, X, N) :-
    maplist(eval_term_(X), Poly, Ps),
    sumlist(Ps, N).
```

Note that the `X` argument have been moved in first position, since maplist/3 calls the *goal* (first argument) with 2 additional arguments - the 2 lists elements processed.

Comment: Dang i just kinda bs’d a version that worked, it was due at 12. But yours is a lot cleaner, ill keep yours to study later thanks!